# Powershell - create new zip folders of a specified size limit and move jpg images from one folder to new zip folders

Tags: function, powershell

I am new to powershell and I am running into an issue that I hope you can help me with:

I am trying to move jpg images from one folder into entirely new zip folders within another folder while each new zip folder does not exceed 95 MB in size. If it reaches 95 MB in size, my function should create another zip folder with new name and continue moving images into it and so on until all images have been copied or moved into zip folders.

I believe my issue lies in my missing do while loop increment but I am not sure what exactly to increment. I may also need to use csv for folder names but please advise your suggestion. Thank you for your help.

```
function createFolders {
    Compress-Archive C:\Desktop\fromfolder\* -DestinationPath C:Desktop\tofolder\NewFolderName -Force
}

function folderSize {
    "{0} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem C:\Desktop\tofolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)
}

do {
createFolders
} while (folderSize -lt 95 MB)
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?  No archive is created, the archive is over 95mb, there is an error message, etc.

Comment: You are short-circuiting your logic. You need to first ...  1 - `Create an empty archive base on the path fed in, if it does not already exist`,   2- `Update the archive with new files until the archive is not greater than 95MB`, then rinse and repeat. Also, what you show here does not take into consideration all possible outcomes. Meaning, single files that are `-gt` 95MB will be in a separate zip, as well as nested folders, etc. There is way more logic that needs to be in this.